# How does Flink work with reading multiple files from HDFS under the hood?

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink

I have an issue: I write sorted (by the specific key e.g. timestamp) data to HDFS into multiple files (each file ~70GB and data is sorted).
I want to read this files by Flink. But I have to be sure in ordering (sorting) of data (across the files).

My question is: how does Flink read files from HDFS? Does it read file by file or read it randomly by blocks of each file?

Comment: This is a very interesting question for me too. Did you get any info so far?

Comment: @omikron unfortunately not. We decided to to stop working on related project for business reason.